# error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'enableIvy'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-ivy

I am trying to add IVY to my angular 7 beta project. So, I added `enableIvy: true` to `src/tsconfig.app.json` in `compilerOptions` section

But when I run `ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing none` I get below error.

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'enableIvy'.

Error: error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'enableIvy'.

    at AngularCompilerPlugin._setupOptions (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:112:19)
    at new AngularCompilerPlugin (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:61:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:41:12)
    at Object.getAotConfig (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:63:19)
    at BrowserBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/index.js:81:37)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.rxjs_1.of.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/index.js:31:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:62:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at ForkJoinSubscriber.notifyComplete (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/observable/forkJoin.js:79:25)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (/Users/k26686/aniruddh/develop/experiment/shepherd/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:32:21)
```

Any one resolved this.

Answer (score 18):

try to include `enableIvy` option under `angularCompilerOptions`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableIvy": true
}
```

Comment: Please have a look to the Stack Overflow guidelines on how to write good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 16):

`compilerOptions` and `angularCompilerOptions` are two separate properties in **tsconfig.json**. You need to add `"enableIvy": true` to `angularCompilerOptions` and not `compilerOptions`:

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  ....
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Now the right way is set

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableIvy": "ngtsc"
}
```

this is related to the issue [#23455](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/23455)

> This commit adds a new compiler pipeline that isn't dependent on global
>   analysis, referred to as 'ngtsc'. This new compiler is accessed by
>   running ngc with "enableIvy" set to "ngtsc". It reuses the same initialization
>   logic but creates a new implementation of Program which does not perform the
>   global-level analysis that AngularCompilerProgram does. It will be the
>   foundation for the production Ivy compiler.

Comment: Now both ways `true` and `ngtsc` should work https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27306